# Nuxt3 - is possible ckeditor5?

Tags: ckeditor5, nuxt3

Can ckeditor5 be used in a Nuxt3 environment?

Window is not defined error occurred
It does not work even though I wrapped it in .

[image: error image]

```js
<template>
    <ClientOnly placeholder="loading...">
        <ckeditor :editor="ClassicEditor" />
    </ClientOnly>
</template>

<script>
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue'

export default defineComponent({
    components: {
        ckeditor: CKEditor,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            ClassicEditor,
        }
    },
})
</script>
```